# Create a site-column of type user, multichoice and multiuser using Sharepoint Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-clientobject, site-column

I'm trying to create site-columns with following types: **Text, Note, Number, Choice, User, MultiUser, MultiChoice**

I've implemented it for all the types except for **User, MultiChoice and MultiUser.** Can't seem to find how to achieve it. This is what I've achieved so far.

```
StringBuilder choiceFieldGenericShema = new StringBuilder();
                choiceFieldGenericShema.Append("<Field Type='Choice' Format='Dropdown' Group='{1}' Name='{0}' DisplayName='{2}' Status='{3}' > <CHOICES> ");
                choiceFieldGenericShema.Append("</CHOICES>  </Field> ");
                string choicFieldSchema = string.Format(choiceFieldGenericShema.ToString(), columnItem.Title, columnItem.GroupName, columnItem.Name, columnItem.Status);
                var newField = web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(choicFieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
                clientContext.Load(newField);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Can anyone please suggest a way following the above method to achieve my task? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at these articles:

- [List with XML declarations of different field types](https://arsferraz.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/sharepoint-field-types-for-elements-xml/)
- [Adding columns to a site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543203(v=office.14).aspx)

In this case, you'll need to tweak with some attributes to toggle multi select for a choice + user field:

Choice:

```
<Field Type="MultiChoice" 
DisplayName="Labels_Selected" 
FillInChoice="FALSE" 
Group="Sample Site Columns" 
ID="{2fdf0ba7-0052-4e9f-80f6-e7669ac4ae4f}"
SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
StaticName="LabelsSelected" Name="LabelsSelected"> 
</Field>
```

User:

```
<Field ID="{A0372EB5-A947-41CA-A5FA-A34C29D2FB88}"
Name="Employee"
DisplayName="Employee"
Type="UserMulti"
Required="TRUE"
StaticName="Employee"
UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly"
Group="SampleGroup"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create site column using `csom`, below is code

```
string schemaChoiceField = "<Field ID='<GUID>' Type='Choice' Name='SideDishesChoice' StaticName='SideDishesChoice' 
   DisplayName='Side dishes' Format='RadioButtons'>"
   + "<Default>Patatoes</Default>"
   +         "<CHOICES>"
   +         "    <CHOICE>Fresh vegetables</CHOICE>"
   +         "    <CHOICE>Beans</CHOICE>"
   +         "</CHOICES>"
   + "</Field>";
```

For dropdown or radio button  follow the link http://projectservercode.com/create-choice-type-site-column-using-csom-sharepoint/